# Why can't I catch process signals when jobs control is enabled in a script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When I enable jobs control into a shell script (using `set -m`), I am no longer able to catch process signals. Take a look at the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -m

for i in `seq 15`; do
    trap 'echo " Signal $i catched"' $i
done

while true; do
    echo " Waiting for a process signal"
    sleep 999
done
```

When I run the above code and I press for example Ctrl + C, nothing happens:

```
Waiting for a process signal
^CWaiting for a process signal
```

However, when I run the same code deleting `set -m`, I do get an answer:

```
Waiting for a process signal
^C Signal 15 catched
```

My questions are:

1. Why is it not working?
2. Is it possible to catch process signals when jobs control is enabled?

Note: It doesn't happen with all processes, if I use `read` instead of `sleep`, it does work.

Comment: Why would you enable job control in a script in the first place?

Comment: Job control works by running external programs in a different process group than the shell. Keyboard signals are only sent to the foreground process group, and while a program is running the shell is not in the foreground group.

Comment: @Barmar In some cases, jobs control is useful in scripts. For example, when I start a new process in background, if I'd need to kill the whole process group in the future, I won't be able to do so. Because, when jobs control is not enabled, new process groups are not created, all created processes will belong to the current group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to put sleep in the background and use a bash builtin, `wait`, to wait while sleep completes.  Thus, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -m

for i in `seq 15`; do
    trap 'echo " Signal $i catched"' $i
done

while true; do
    echo " Waiting for a process signal"
    sleep 999 & wait $!
done
```

Sample run:

```
$ bash script
 Waiting for a process signal
^C Signal 15 catched
 Waiting for a process signal
^C Signal 15 catched
 Waiting for a process signal
```

For more details, see [Greg's FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap).

Comment: What makes this solution even better is that, not only works perfectly, but also will work with any called program. Because, no matter what program is called, it will be put on background, and `wait` will be on the foreground catching all signals.